# install app widget from android application

Tags: android, widget

I'm trying to find a way to install a widget on the home screen/launcher, from my app, rather than from the launcher itself.

Since the default launcher doesn't seem to have a way to allow this I assume it's not.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to programmatically add your widget to any arbitrary launcher that users may be using.